# Change values in DF Column based first digit of value in another DF Column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe and for my purposes, when the first digit in the Subref is X, the Centre should be X and when the fist letter of the Subref is Y, the Centre value should be Y.

So how do I go from this df

```
 Subref     Det      Centre
0   C12345  JOHNEL      1
1    C3245    BVDI      3
2  X035769  JOHNEL      0
3  Y038450    BVDI      0
```

To this df

```
 Subref     Det      Centre
0   C12345  JOHNEL      1
1    C3245    BVDI      3
2  X035769  JOHNEL      X
3  Y038450    BVDI      Y
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str[0]` to get the first character, then `where` or `loc` or `np.where` to replace

```
first_chars = df['Subref'].str[0]

df['Centre'] = df['Centre'].where(first_chars=='C', first_chars)

# or 
# df['Centre'] = np.where(first_char=='C', df['Center'], first_chars)

# or
# df.loc[first_chars!='C', 'Centre'] = first_chars
```

Output:

```
    Subref     Det Centre
0   C12345  JOHNEL      1
1    C3245    BVDI      3
2  X035769  JOHNEL      X
3  Y038450    BVDI      Y
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
df.loc[df['Subref'].str[0].isin(['X','Y']),'Centre'] = df['Subref'].str[0]
print(df)
```